# Request HTML and handle special characters

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

What is the best way to handle special characters by requesting an html page.

I want to use the npm request library and my code looks like this:

```
const request = require('request');

request(url, function (error, response, html) {
  console.log(html);
})
```

The special characters are just shown as questionmark. How is it possible to avoid this?

Comment: where are the question marks displaying and what are they?

Comment: Instead of the special characters. i guess it is "ISO 8859-1" coded and interpreted as "UTF-8"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the numeric codes in your HTML document? For example using % instead of %. That could solve your issue.

Comment: I mean & # 3 7 ; instead of the percentage(%).

Answer (score 0):

```
return mystring.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
```

Maybe try to replace the special characters using mystring